How can I understand (with alias, temporary var etc) which of the OR statements is matching and returning the rows?
I'm coding a WHERE statement with OR in it. I'd like to get field that indicates me which OR is matched, without using different SQL query. So, for example, if I'm matching the title get a field with the value to true or, get back a field with title as the value.
Stack: PHP, Mariadb
Here the query I'm testing:
SELECT * 
FROM books 
WHERE title LIKE :s OR 
      description LIKE :s OR 
      author LIKE :s .... 


what is your dmbs?

Syntax error. You are trying to do WHERE title LIKE (:s || description) LIKE .... Concatenation goes before both LIKE and OR.

Note that tables have columns, not fields.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

In standard SQL OR is OR, not ||, which is concatenation of character values.

What's the expected result if two or three columns match?

this is not possible "without using different SQL query", but easily possible with adding to your selected columns

The value of a search condition can be evaluated within the SELECT clause using a case statement.
SELECT *,
   CASE 
    WHEN title LIKE '%:s%' THEN 'title ' + title
    WHEN description LIKE '%:s%' THEN 'description ' +description
    WHEN author LIKE '%:s%' THEN 'author ' +author
    END as MatchingValue
FROM books 
WHERE title LIKE '%:s%' OR 
      description LIKE '%:s%' OR 
      author LIKE '%:s%'  

fiddle



id
title
description
author
MatchingValue




1
Foo
Foo goe:s to town
Bob
description Foo goe:s to town


2
Bar:s
Bar gets killed
Ann
title Bar:s


3
Roo
Roo gets maried
:sam
author :sam




more examples and handling of multiple matches https://dbfiddle.uk/0MYb5CFX

Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP and the rest of us which dbms this is for.

Bart solution works VERY GOOD! Thanks

@jarlh Seems to work for SQL-Server and mariadb

@BartMcEndree, yes, I noticed that too.

case is inappropriate for this, since it will not show when a later condition succeeds if an earlier one does.

@ysth I considered that. See my first comment on this answer.

Use case expressions to find each matching column:
SELECT *,
   CONCAT_WS(', ',
             CASE WHEN title LIKE '%:s%' THEN 'title' END,
             CASE WHEN description LIKE '%:s%' THEN 'description' END,
             CASE WHEN author LIKE '%:s%' THEN 'author' END) matches
FROM books 
WHERE title LIKE '%:s%' OR 
      description LIKE '%:s%' OR 
      author LIKE '%:s%'  

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/Jly-gX6z (Using @Bart's fiddle as base, thanks!)
